# Solution to make all videos properly work in Epyphany

Tags: release-juno, epiphany

I didn't get any 720p youtube videos in Epiphany and no streaming videos at fresh install. The I installed `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` and most videos/streaming work, but on youtube only some videos play at 720p, some only at 360p (and those are available at 720p, I checked with Firefox and Chrome). Is there another solution for this? I remember in Loki/Freya I installed flash for this, but I don't want to do that anymore. 
P.S.: Don't send me to Epiphany's gitlab, I've already checked. I'm asking it here because I presume the majority of Epiphany users are on eOS.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the other videos require the media source extensions API (MSE) in order for you to receive high-quality videos. WebKitGTK+, the web engine powering Epiphany, requires GStreamer 1.14.4 to enable MSE, but unfortunately elementary has an older version of GStreamer and is unlikely update it since it's part of the base system inherited from Ubuntu. Most likely you're out of luck until the next version of elementary based on Ubuntu 20.04 is released, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This problem got solved after some updates this week. Also, even 1080p videos play now in youtube. I still have `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` installed, I don't know what got updated. So I think this issue can be closed.

Comment: this is not an issue tracker ;)